# Using initializer for weakly typed assignment

Tags: c#, syntax

I like the syntax:

```
Something something = new Something
{
  Property1 = "property1",
  Property2 = "property2"
}
```

but in the current project, I see the following:

```
Something something = new Something();
something["Property1"] = "property1";
something["Property2"] = "property2";
```

I wonder if there's a way to refactor the latter to somehow embrace the syntax of the latter. I tried to see what intellisense would suggest but didn't get any more clever. Suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you can change it to an [`Expando Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)

Comment: Either overloading an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) with a little bit of reflection or a dynamic with ExpandoObject would give you the second version...

Comment: Is `Something` some kind of dynamic object?

Comment: @Magnus Nope, not a dynamic object. I think I'll leave it be for now. Not sure enough to motivate the change to the rest of the team.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something is a Dictionary then

```
Something something = new Something()
{
    {"Property1", "property1"},
    {"Property2", "property2"}
}
```